# Zero-coupon bond price in the risk-neutral word

Tags: forward-rate, hullwhite, zero-coupon

In Hull's technical note ([http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/~hull/technicalnotes/TechnicalNote31.pdf](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/%7Ehull/technicalnotes/TechnicalNote31.pdf)), on page 3, in the third row from the bottom, a plus sign suddenly appears before σ dz in an expression for the differential dr(t). However, above that, there is a minus sign for the very same differential dr(t) used three times. I understand that in these models, there should be a plus sign; however, I cannot find a mistake in the preceding derivation on page 1 ending with formulae (5) and (6).

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Is it because the sign doesn’t matter since dZ is completely symmetrical

Comment: Pls add details to your question in case the link you have provided gets broken, etc.

Comment: @dm63 But the resulting stochastic integral of "minus the integrand" wrt dZ changes the sign, does it not? So it does not matter in the sense of distribution, right? And if so, then I still don't understant why J. Hull writes e.g. in Case 1 "and equation (6) gives" without any note on why there is plus sign or that the equality should be understood in law.